# chromedriver.exe has stopped working when driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.example.com/")

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Upon reaching `navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.example.com/")` chromedriver.exe will stop working, but it's working when the FirefoxDriver is being used:

```
using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(DRIVER_PATH))
{
    // driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    INavigation navigate = driver.Navigate();
    navigate.GoToUrl("http://www.example.com/");
}
```

1. Chrome browser will successfully open.
2. Then a few second "chromedriver.exe has stopped working" will appear.

Here's my debug.log file:

```
[0508/115012.911:ERROR:process_reader_win.cc(114)] NtOpenThread: {Access Denied} A process has requested access to an object, but has not been granted those access rights.  (0xc0000022)
[0508/115012.912:ERROR:exception_snapshot_win.cc(87)] thread ID 7968 not found in process
[0508/115012.912:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(60)] ProcessSnapshotWin::Initialize failed
```

- ChromeDriver v2.9.248315 (chromedriver_win32.zip)
- Google Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit)

Can anyone guess how to make it work in C#?

Comment: Can you bump up your ChromeDriver version to latest 2.29.x ?

Comment: @Dev That's the latest version.

Comment: @5ervant Actually 2.9 is quite an old one, from 3 years ago. 2.29 is the newest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To work with Selenium 3.4.0 you need to have latest ChromeDriver 2.29.x from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) & latest Google Chrome 58.0

I don't see any issues in your code as such.

You might need to check if `navigate` have `GoToUrl` method implemented or not in C#.

As in Java we do it like this:

```
WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver(c1);
Navigation navigate = driver1.navigate();
navigate.to("https://gmail.com");
```

Comment: I didn't expect that the zip file that I've extracted was the old version, thanks for reminding. Such kind of mistake make my time hard..